# Webpack неправильный порядок подключения библиотек

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, npm

Библиотеки подключаются в разном порядке. Библиотека, использующая, например, jquery может подключиться перед jquery или вообще после пользовательского кода т.е. сначала в бандле идет свой код, а потом библиотека. С чем это может быть связано и как исправить?
Файл js:

```
import '~/js/modules/common';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';
var buttons = require( 'datatables.net-buttons' )();
var moment = require('moment');
import datepicker from 'air-datepicker';
import qtip from 'qtip2';
import noUiSlider from 'nouislider';
import wNumb from 'wnumb';
var showdown  = require('showdown');
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import tippy from 'tippy.js';

window.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, () => {
... какой-то js код
});
```

Конфиг Вебпака:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const SpriteLoaderPlugin = require('svg-sprite-loader/plugin');

// Main const
const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, `./assets/src`),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, `./assets/dist`),
  assets: `assets`
};

module.exports = {
  externals: {
    paths: PATHS
  },
  entry: {
    jsfile: `${PATHS.src}/js/pages/jsfile`,
  },
  output: {
    filename: `js/[name].js`,
    path: PATHS.dist,
    publicPath: `/`
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
      test: /\.js$/i,
      exclude: `/node_modules/`,
      use: [
        `cache-loader`,
        {
          loader: `babel-loader`,
          options: { cacheDirectory: true }
        }
      ],
    }, {
      test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/i,
      use: [
        `cache-loader`,
        {
          loader: `file-loader`,
          options: { name: `[name].[ext]` }
        }
      ],
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        `cache-loader`,
        {
          loader: `file-loader`,
          options: { name: `[name].[ext]` }
        }
      ],
    }, {
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      loader: `svg-sprite-loader`,
      options: {
        extract: true,
        spriteFilename: `img/sprite.svg`,
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/i,
      use: [
        `style-loader`,
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        `cache-loader`,
        {
          loader: `css-loader`,
          options: { sourceMap: true, url: false }
        }, {
          loader: `postcss-loader`,
          options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: `./postcss.config.js` } }
        }, {
          loader: `sass-loader`,
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        }
      ]
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: [
        `style-loader`,
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        `cache-loader`,
        {
          loader: `css-loader`,
          options: { sourceMap: true }
        }, {
          loader: `postcss-loader`,
          options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: `./postcss.config.js` } }
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      [`~`]: PATHS.src,
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: `jquery`,
    }),
    new SpriteLoaderPlugin({
      plainSprite: true
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: `css/[name].css`,
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: `${PATHS.src}/static`, to: `` },
      { from: `${PATHS.src}/${PATHS.assets}/img`, to: `img` },
      { from: `${PATHS.src}/${PATHS.assets}/fonts`, to: `fonts` },
    ])
  ],
};
```

Comment: А почему у вас import и require вперемешку? Вообще по стандарту все import-ы поднимаются наверх, так что лучше их сразу писать сверху не перемешивая с другими выражениями

Comment: Это не играет роли, я оставлял только свой код и подключение buttons for datatables и эта библиотека, все равно, после самого кода в бандл формировалась

Comment: эээ, порядок кода в бандле вообще не связан с порядком выполнения этого кода.

Comment: Все верно, сбили с толку комментарии к библиотекам! Спасибо за наводку!